# Switching to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch Causes Connection Refusal

Tags: cassandra, centos7, cassandra-3.0

I have brand new install of Cassandra 3.0.9 on CentOS 7.4.1708.
I am trying to change from the default SimpleSnitch to GosspingPropertyFileSnitch.

When I try and follow the steps on the [DatStax Website](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsSwitchSnitch.html?hl=switchin%2Csnitch), it appears as though I should only have to change the endpoint_snitch setting in the cassandra.yaml file. When I do that and restart the cassandra service, I am no longer able to connect to cassandra with nodetool or cqlsh (Connection Refused). Changing the settign back to the SimpleSnitch yields no reversal and ability to connect. I am confused as to what settings I am missing that are causing this to happen. I'd like to know

1. What I am missing in trying to get it moved to the GossipingPropertyFileSnitch?
2. Why changing the setting back does not revert things to its previous state where I can connect using nodetool or cqlsh?

I have two nodes in the cluster, both of which I want to act as seeds.

**cassandra.yaml: - Node 1**

```
cluster_name: '<My Cluster Name>'
- seeds: "<IP Add1>, <IP Add2>"
listen_address: <IP Add1>
rpc_address: <IP Add1>
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
#broadcast_address: 1.2.3.4
```

**cassandra.yaml: - Node 2**

```
cluster_name: '<My Cluster Name>'
- seeds: "<IP Add1>, <IP Add2>"
listen_address: <IP Add2>
rpc_address: <IP Add2>
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
#broadcast_address: 1.2.3.4
```

**cassandra-rackdc.properties - Node 1:**

```
dc=<DC1 Name>
rack=rack1
prefer_local=true
```

**cassandra-rackdc.properties - Node 2:**

```
dc=<DC1 Name>
rack=rack2
prefer_local=true
```

**cassandra-topology.properties - Both Nodes:**

```
<IP Add1>=<DC1 Name>:RAC1
<IP Add2>=<DC1 Name>:RAC2
```

**In CQLSH - Both Nodes**

```
UPDATE system.local SET cluster_name = '<My Cluster Name>' where key='local';
```

Comment: Can you please add your `cassandra-rackdc.properties` and relevant sections in the `cassandra.yaml` (seed_provider, endpoint_snitch, listen_address, broadcast_address)? I also assume from your question, that you're using only one node. Is that right?

Comment: If you have more than one node, please describe your network topology: Number of nodes in the cluster, external-internal IP addresses

Comment: Execute this command `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/*` before making changes to .yaml file and restart the cassandra service.

Comment: What's strange is that, sometimes, a restart is needed. In some cases, simply restarting cassandra is fine.

Comment: @Akshay-Nevrekar Good point. That seems to have been the kicker.

Comment: @Flea did it work?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your help. It wasn't marked as an answer so I could only give a + to the comment. Becasue Cassandra stores its state on disk it wasn't picking up the changes until the on-disk state had been purged as per your comment. Also, Purging gossip state on a node:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_gossip_purge.html